# How do you decide the user chosen language(or locale) in Android programming?

Tags: android, android-fragments, localization, internationalization, main-activity

In main activity, I show users set of languages.

```
<RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textViewSelection"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/english_lang"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
        android:text="@string/langtext_english"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:padding="10dp" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/indonesian_lang"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
        android:text="@string/langtext_indonesian"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:padding="10dp" />
</RadioGroup>
```

When user selects a language , I jump to onRadioButtonClicked() method located inside MainActivityFragment.java class

```
 public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view){
        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

        // Check which radio button was clicked
        switch(view.getId()) {
            case R.id.english_lang:
                if (checked)
                    //
                    break;
            case R.id.french_lang:
                if (checked)
                    // Ninjas rule
                    break;
        }

    }
```

Under res directory, I have created a new folder called values-fr and I placed a string.xml with french values.

1) How should I pass on the user chosen language to the entire app context and use it FURTHER and FOREVER?

2) Why is my    method never used?

MainActivityFragment.java

```
package com.a2ndnumber.a2ndnumber;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.RadioButton;

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

    private ArrayAdapter<String> countryList_Adapter;

    public MainActivityFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }


    public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view){
        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

        // Check which radio button was clicked
        switch(view.getId()) {
            case R.id.english_lang:
                if (checked)
                    //
                    break;
            case R.id.indonesian_lang:
                if (checked)
                    // Ninjas rule
                    break;
        }

    }

    /*
   * When user is selecting the country, in background we grab 25 numbers of each country,
   * so that we are ready in next fragment where we let them choose the number
   * */
    public class FetchNumbers_Task extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

        private final String LOG_TAG = FetchNumbers_Task.class.getSimpleName();

        /**
         * Override this method to perform a computation on a background thread. The
         * specified parameters are the parameters passed to {@link #execute}
         * by the caller of this task.
         * <p/>
         * This method can call {@link #publishProgress} to publish updates
         * on the UI thread.
         *
         * @param params The parameters of the task.
         * @return A result, defined by the subclass of this task.
         * @see #onPreExecute()
         * @see #onPostExecute
         * @see #publishProgress
         */
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the language of the app using below code :

```
    public void setLocale(String lang) {
    myLocale = new Locale(lang);
    Resources res = getResources();
    DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
    Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
    conf.locale = myLocale;
    res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
    Intent refresh = new Intent(this, Youractivity.class); // refresh the activity 
    refresh.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP); 
    refresh.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(refresh);
    finish();
    }
```

And to get the click listener of Radio Buttons use :

```
mRadioHindi.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            if (b){
                Log.d("SettingsActivity::","onCheckedChanged hindi" + b);
                PreferenceManager.saveLanguage("hi");
                setLocale("hi");
            }
        }
    });
```

Use setOnCheckedChangeListener for all the radio buttons.

Save the language in shared preference and next time when the user opens the app, get the language from sharedPreference and call setLocale() method.

Comment: In the activity where you have the options of selecting languages.

Comment: I have an activity and its fragment. So where should it go and under which method?

Comment: I am getting cannot resolve PreferenceManager.saveLanguage("hi")

Comment: This is used to save language in sharedPreference. You use your sharedpreference method to save.

Comment: Lets say I have this in ActivityA, which is the first activity user sees after opening the app. Lets say he choses language hindi, he moves to Activity B, then ActivityC. Then he comes back to ActivityB then to ActivityA. Now user selects English and goes to ActivityB, al texts except label are translated to English. How to fix this?

Comment: Also there is no saveLanguage() method for PreferenceManager.